# Database in recovery - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

Tengo este problema con mi base de datos, está pesa aprox 90GB.

Mi base de datos está en montada en Windows Server 2016 Standard con Sql Server 2008 R2

[image: mi base de datos está en montada en Windows Server 2016 Standard con Sql Server 2008 R2]
Intente darle solución con algunos comandos que encontré en google pero el problema persiste y ahora es frecuente.
Lo peor es que este error[**In recovery**] se realiza automáticamente y de la nada. Luego  en cuestión de 30 minutos o aveces un poco más se soluciona de manera automática,pero dicha solución  es de manera temporal.

Por favor, si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Comment: Hola Gonzalo Rios: Tienes que mejorar un poco la pregunta. Que quieres decir con se realiza automáticamente. Que quieres decir con no necesito ejecutar querys.

Comment: Hola Javi, ya modifique mi pregunta, pero en resumidas tengo problemas con mi base de datos, se pasa a modo In Recovery de la nada, y después de 30 0 40 minutos la base de datos vuelve a estar disponible. Tienes alguna idea de cómo solucionar esto?

Comment: Eso suele ser síntoma de un disco en mal estado. Si puedes, cambia la base de datos a otro disco

Comment: Wow, pero es algo que puedes confirmar. Tendrás algunas sentencias que pueda ejecutar para determinar eso?

Comment: Coincido con @Roger Tomé. Tendrás que escanear el disco. Puedes chequear el estado de la base de datos después de que se ponga en modo online, aunque mucho me temo, que el Sql te la habrá dejado coherente, (se habrá saltado los sectores donde no puede escribir, colocando la info en otros). https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 Puedes mirar el log, porque habrá dejado rastro de los errores

Comment: Ok Javi, realizaré esos procesos. Una consulta, crees que si clono mi servidor tal cual está y lo paso a otro disco esto pueda solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que están sugiriendo en los comentarios es para cuando la base de datos queda como Suspect. Cuando queda In Recovery, es porque se inició un proceso de restauración y no se completó.

Hay varias razones por las que una base de datos puede entrar en ese estado sin razón aparente.

1. **Está configurada para cerrarse automáticamente**. Al abrir la base de datos, entra a un proceso de recuperación para verificar que todo esté en orden. Para corregir eso, hay que cambiar las opciones y poner AUTO_CLOSE como OFF.

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE UnEncryptedDB SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF;
```

2. **El log de transacciones se llenó y no se puede utilizar la base de datos**. Para corregir eso, hay que asegurarse de que el log tenga un espacio suficiente para las operaciones y que se estén realizando los respaldos del log de manera correcta en caso de que no esté en modo de recuperación `Simple`. También hay que verificar que no se queden abiertas transacciones explicitas durante mucho tiempo.
3. **Problemas de hardware**. Revisa que los discos estén en buen estado para evitar que la base de datos se cierre y llegue al punto de estar corrupta y entre al estado Suspect. Una vez en ese estado, lo mejor que se puede hacer es restaurar todo desde el último respaldo sin corrupción.

Por último, nunca está de más hacer continuamente revisiones de la integridad de la base de datos para adelantarte a los problemas. Eso se hace con el siguiente comando:

```
DBCC CHECKDB nombre_Base_datos ALL_ERRORMSGS, NO_INFOMSGS;
```

Si empiezas a obtener resultados ahí, necesitas tomar cartas en el asunto inmediatamente antes de perder completamente la información.

Comment: Gracias Luis, tomare en cuenta todo esto.

Comment: La comprobación que realice a mi base de datos arrojo estos mensajes: CHECKDB detectó 0 errores de asignación y 0 errores de coherencia en la base de datos 'BASEDEDATOS'.
Ejecución de DBCC completada. Si hay mensajes de error, consulte al administrador del sistema. No reporta ningun tipo de error, y tambein configure el AUTO_CLOSE en OFF. Hice la revisión de discos duros del servidor y no presentas fallas. Alguna idea adicional que pueda aplicar?

Comment: Revisaste el log de transacciones? Se está respaldando correctamente o tiene que estar creciendo constantemente?